# Property invalidates value to modify pseudo elements with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that with Javascript it is not possible to directly modify the pseudo elements before and after, however, if I have seen and verified that using attributes we can get to modify these pseudo elements.

My problem is that trying to modify the width of a created element tells me that the property of the value is not valid and checking types and values, the width is exactly the same as the value of what I try to pass.

```
.rombo .fusion-text::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100px;
  height: 0;
  border-right: rgba(12, 201, 232, 0.5);
  border-right-width: 100px;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-top: transparent;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: attr(data-content);
 }

$('.rombo .fusion-text').attr('data-content','503px');

$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.rombo .fusion-text').attr('data-content',$('.rombo .fusion- 
  text').css('height'));
  //alert(typeof($('.rombo .fusion-text').attr('data-content')));
   alert($('.rombo .fusion-text').css('width'));
 });
```

I'm going to stress that obviously the js code right now does not do anything, since directly in the code inspector I get this error.

[[image]

I know it works in other cases because I checked it myself, but I do not know how to make it work in this case.

Comment: FYI: `before` and `after` are pseudo-elements and should be prefixed with `::`, not `:`. The single colon still works in most browsers but that is legacy code.

Comment: Thanks, although that does not solve my doubt it is good to know.

Comment: The `attr()` function obtains the value of the attribute you specify on the current selector element. You are setting the attribute on `.fusion-text` but the selector isn't looking at that element, it's attempting to look at the `.fusion-text::before` pseudo-element, which does not have the `data-content` attribute. I don't see how that would ever work.

Comment: Not only has it worked for me, but for many people except that they modified other styles like content. I try to modify the width of an edge.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a smart solution for the question. Congrats.

Try to solve this problem, specifying the second arg of attr in the css file. As [you can see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) there is a specific flag to px and other properties like this. I think that you will have to ommit the "px" too:

```
$('.rombo .fusion-text').attr('data-content','503');
```

I'm not confident that it will work, is something new for me too